# how to null pandas variable based on date comparison

Tags: pandas, lambda, apply

In the below code I'm trying to create a new variable var1 which is identical to a new variable var2, except that it's null if var1 is greater than 2021/1/1.

```
df_jan['var2'] = df_jan['var1'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x['var1']>pd.Timestamp(2021,1,20))
```

I'm just getting a "syntax error" response.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey! Updated answer(corrected a typo)...Kindly have a look ***:)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `else` statement as well if you are using `if` statement inside `apply()` method:

so try:

```
df_jan['var2'] = df_jan['var1'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x>pd.Timestamp(2021,1,20) else x)
```

btw `apply()` is loop under the hood so for better performance you can use:

`Series.mask()` method:

```
df_jan['var2']=df_jan['var1'].mask(df_jan['var1']>pd.Timestamp(2021,1,20))
```

**OR**

`Series.where()` method:

```
df_jan['var2']=df_jan['var1'].where(~(df_jan['var1']>pd.Timestamp(2021,1,20)))
```

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry haven't been active on SO for a while.